# Add time to current-time in BPEL process Oracle 10G

Tags: oracle, xpath, xquery, soa, bpel

Hi I had this source of code

```
<from expression="concat(substring(xp20:current-dateTime(),1,(string-length(xp20:current-dateTime())-6)),'Z')"/>
```

this works fine and return a date like this:

```
 2014-04-29T03:00:22Z
```

but I need add 10 seconds to the date and I try this:

```
 <from expression="concat(substring(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT10S'),1,(string-length(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT10S'))-6)),'Z')"/>
```

and this return only:

```
 Z
```

This is for Oracle BPEL 10G

With this

```
<from expression="concat(substring(string(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT10S')),1,(string-length(string(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT10S')))-6)),'Z')"/>
```

return

```
Z
```

But if I change only PT10S with PT1M  works OK

```
<from expression="concat(substring(string(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT1M')),1,(string-length(string(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(), 'PT1M')))-6)),'Z')"/>
```

return

```
2014-04-30T13:58:57Z
```

Maybe add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime ignore the seconds, with PT1M10S only add 1M

Answer (score 0):

I can't test against Oracle, so I am not sure what is going on in your XPath, it basically looks correct. Based on the documentation it looks like Oracle supports `format-dateTime`. Then you can write the much more simpler and cleaner

```
xp20:format-dateTime(xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "PT10S"), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]Z")
```

to get the proper formatting you want to achieve

Comment: I tested and the compilation says: "could not resolve xpath function "tokenize", because function "tokenize" not registered" 
And the same problem with dayTimeDuration... I dont know the correct namespace, but thanks  :(

Comment: I updated my answer and I hope it reflects what Oracle supports, based on the doc at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11036_01/integrate.1013/b28981/app_xpath_functions.htm#CJAIABIC